# regex to match literally the characters of an abbreviation

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, text

I am new with regex and I would like some help. So I have a string below and I want to make my regex match the first character of the acronym literally + any character[a-z] unlimited times but only for the first character. For the rest of the characters, i would like to just match them as they are. Any help on what to change on my regex line to achieve this, would be highly appreciated.

```
import re
s = 'nUSA stands for northern USA'
x = (f'({"nUSA"}).+?({" ".join( t[0] + "[a-z]" + t[1:] for t in "nUSA")})(?: )')
print(x)
out: (nUSA).+?(n[a-z]+ U[a-z]+ S[a-z]+ A[a-z]+)(?: )
```

What i want to achieve with my regex line is something like the pattern below so that it can match for the northern USA.

```
(nUSA).+?(n[a-z]+ U + S + A)(?: )
```

instead of the one i get

```
(nUSA).+?(n[a-z]+ U[a-z]+ S[a-z]+ A[a-z]+)(?: )
```

I would like it to work for any arbitrary text, not only for the specific one. I am not sure if i have expressed my problem properly.

Comment: If `nUSA` is assigned to `key` variable, try `x = rf'({key}).+?({key[0]}[a-z]*\s*{key[1:]})(?!\S)'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/fuRcNS).

Comment: Thank you very much. How can i make it match for only whole words for the first character?

Comment: You'll find online regexp checkers to be invaluable for this type of thing.  They allow you to test lots of options very quickly.  A quick Google will find several.  The only warning is to make sure the tester you select covers the language you are using.  (Because say Perl RexExp is slightly different than C# RexExp is slightly different than Python RexExp, etc)

Comment: `x = rf'\b({key})\b.+?\b({key[0]}[a-z]*\s*{key[1:]})(?!\S)'`

Comment: See my answer below, and let me know if there are any problems still. If not, please consider accepting.

Comment: If you have questions related to this problem, please drop a line here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = 'nUSA stands for northern USA'
key='nUSA'
x = rf'\b({key})\b.+?\b({key[0]}[a-z]*\s*{key[1:]})(?!\S)'
# => print(x) => \b(nUSA)\b.+?\b(n[a-z]*\s*USA)(?!\S)
# Or, if the key can contain special chars at the end:
# x = rf'\b({re.escape(key)})(?!\w).+?(?<!\w)({re.escape(key[0])}[a-z]*\s*{re.escape(key[1:])})(?!\S)'
print(re.findall(x, s))
# => [('nUSA', 'northern USA')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Chpiit). The resulting regex will look like `\b(nUSA)\b.+?\b(n[a-z]*\s*USA)(?!\S)`, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/zmPBov/1). Details:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(nUSA)` - Group 1 capturing the key word
- `\b` / `(?!\w)` - word boundary (right-hand word boundary)
- `.+?` - any 1+ chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(n[a-z]*\s*USA)`  - Group 2: `n` (first char), then any 0+ lowercase ASCII letters, 0+ whitespaces and the rest of the `key` string.
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary (you may consider using `(?!\w)` again here).